# Getting $Scope.Form undefined. What is the best way to handle ready state, so the form is available?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following controller, where I am getting the form as **'undefined'**.

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyController',['$scope', function(){

      $(document).ready(function () { 

      var form = $scope.Form1; // undefined

      }]);
  });
```

What is the best way to handle ready state, so the form is available?

Comment: frankly speaking you don't need ready here.

Comment: Could you please provide HTML. If you have a form with name=Form1, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass $scope into your controller function. **Correction:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyController',['$scope', function($scope){ //$scope in function here

      $(document).ready(function () { 

      var form = $scope.Form1; // undefined

      }]);
  });
```

Also, you dont really need jQuery here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
'MyController',['$scope', function(){
```

with

```
'MyController',['$scope', function($scope){
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you miss:

1. a blank array when creating angular module. `angular.module('app', [])`.
2. `$scope` in the function arguement `function($scope){`.

---

Just make a proper selector and pass `$scope` in the func args:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController',['$scope', function($scope){ // <---pass $scope here
    $scope.Form1 = document.querySelector('form')
}]);
```

---

A sample test is below:

```js
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('formController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.form = document.querySelector('form');
    $scope.getValue= function(){
      alert($scope.form.id);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app='testApp'>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <form ng-controller='formController' id='testForm'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='dummy text to be placed' autofocus ng-focus='getValue()'>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `$scope` argument in your `function()`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is not an issue , I have written on the fly that is why the code is buggy.

But I have resolved the issue by moving this code in the directive => link and I am getting `$scope.Form1`.